# Lodash equals function

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, underscore.js, lodash

I need to make several operations with given map:

```
var keys = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
  c: 1,
  d: 2,
  e: 2
}
_.findKey(keys, function(value) {
   return value === 2;
}); // "b"
_.omit(keys, function(value) {
   return value === 2;
}); // {a: 1, c: 1}
```

I want to instantly create callbacks with comparison. Something like this

```
function equals(lhs) {
    return function(rhs) {
        return lhs === rhs;
    };
}
```

Do the lodash or underscore have equivalent of this function? I've tried to make a callback by `_.matches(2)`, but it makes a deep compare and don't work on primitive types.

Of course, I can create it by myself, but I am looking for a way to do it in a common way.

Comment: What output are you expecting for `keys`?

Comment: updated code sample. Now here are comments with expected results

Comment: I'm still unclear what you are trying to do.  Are you trying to replace the calls `_.findKey` and `_.omit` and use something else?

Comment: I want to have to generate callbacks for `_.findKey`, `_.omit` and others, which compares passed value with some constant

Comment: I'm not how you would do this but I'm pretty sure you could use the latest version of underscore and the _.mapObject function to iterate through the object and get the results you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if I fully understand your question, but here's my best guess at what you're after.

```
function equals(val) {
    return _.ary(_.partial(_.isEqual, val), 1);
}

_.findKey(keys, equals(2));
// → 'b'

_.omit(keys, equals(2));
// { a: 1, c:1 }
```

Here, `equals()` will return a callback function. It uses [ary()](https://lodash.com/docs#ary) to make sure only one argument is passed. It uses [partial()](https://lodash.com/docs#partial) to apply the `val` argument to [isEqual()](https://lodash.com/docs#isEqual). This is then compared against each value in the collection.

Comment: Brilliant! Looks like this is the best way to do it via lodash. But there is significant performance impact. So I think to extend lodash with method which can do it in one function